# Where/What is "Remainder" in New Relic

Tags: cakephp, newrelic

I have a cake php project and my trace report a "**Remainder**" cosuming 25% of my server time.

**Remainder** don't exist in my project.

What is "**Remainder**" ?Where is "**Remainder**"?

Any help?

[image]

Comment: fyi- it is **RemAinder** not **Reminder**

Comment: I found it now , solved,

Answer (score 4):

I found it!

> Hi again @gguirand
>
> Just to further clarify this as I have a bit more of an addendum to
>   the above response.
>
> The transaction trace summary chart only shows the top 6 components
>   that contributed the most to transaction time for the trace in
>   question.
>
> All other components are bundled together as "Remainder". In other
>   words, the transaction trace Summary chart will only ever show 7
>   components, with one being "Remainder". The "Trace Details" tab will
>   list all instrumented components, including those bundled as
>   Remainder.